# Tmux scroll in readonly

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to scroll up in read-only mode of tmux?

I have scripts that run for a very long time, and I do not want to spoil it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, while checking the output.

Answer (score 0):

#### Keyboard shortcut

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd>
This will allow you to scroll up with arrow keys while your application continues. Press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit this mode.

#### Mouse shortcut

In your `~./tmux.config` file add the line `set-option -g mouse on`.  Now you can scroll with the mouse.  Press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit this mode.

#### Note

Adding `set -g history 65000` to `~./tmux.config` will help keep more data in the history buffer